# How to add system instructions when using chainlit x LlamaIndex with StorageContext?

Tags: openai-api, langchain, large-language-model, llama-index

```py
try:
    # rebuild storage context
    storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(persist_dir="./storage")
    # load index
    index = load_index_from_storage(storage_context)
except:
    from llama_index import GPTVectorStoreIndex, SimpleDirectoryReader

    documents = SimpleDirectoryReader("./data").load_data()
    index = GPTVectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents)
    index.storage_context.persist()

@cl.on_chat_start
async def factory():
    llm_predictor = LLMPredictor(
        llm=ChatOpenAI(
            temperature=0,
            model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo",
            streaming=True,
            # openai_api_key=API_KEY
        ),
    )
    service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(
        llm_predictor=llm_predictor,
        chunk_size=512,
        callback_manager=CallbackManager([cl.LlamaIndexCallbackHandler()]),
    )

    query_engine = index.as_query_engine(
        service_context=service_context,
        streaming=True,
    )

    cl.user_session.set("query_engine", query_engine)


@cl.on_message
async def main(message):
    query_engine = cl.user_session.get("query_engine")  # type: RetrieverQueryEngine
    response = await cl.make_async(query_engine.query)(message)

    response_message = cl.Message(content="")

    for token in response.response_gen:
        await response_message.stream_token(token=token)

    if response.response_txt:
        response_message.content = response.response_txt

    await response_message.send()
```

Hello folks,

A beginner here.

I have some text files in the 'data' folder
How can I add custom instructions that will be followed while generating any answer.
An example could be : "Answer like a pirate would"
Very basic thing I can think of is : Adding this line in "About you.txt" in the data folder.

Overwhelmed. Can anyone also suggest a learning path for langchain?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any vector store database, you can easily achieve this with filter. I believe you have done 75% of work and created the indexes, you can further store this in vector db.

Loading and splitting the documents

```
    def load_source_documents(folder_path):
        all_documents = []
        dir_loaders = [DirectoryLoader(folder_path, glob="**/*.txt")]
        #print(doc_loaders)
        
        for loader in dir_loaders:
            document = loader.load()
            all_documents.extend(document)

        return all_documents

    def split_documents(documents):
        text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=40)
        chunked_documents = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)

        return chunked_documents
```

Using data lake and retrieving the result from vector db, you find separate columns gets created with metadata and you can filter based on this filter. This also help that you fetch result only from relevant documents

```
  def setup_datalake_add_documents(chunked_documents, org_id, dataset_name):
        #embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(model="text-embedding-ada-002")
        embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
        my_activeloop_org_id = org_id 
        my_activeloop_dataset_name = dataset_name 
        dataset_path = f"hub://{my_activeloop_org_id}/{my_activeloop_dataset_name}"
        db = DeepLake(dataset_path=dataset_path, embedding_function=embeddings)

        # add documents to our Deep Lake dataset
        #db.add_documents(chunked_documents)
        
        return db 

    def query_datalake(db, query, subject):

        filter={"metadata": {"source": f"output\\{subject}.txt"}}  
        #Distance function L2 for Euclidean, L1 for Nuclear, Max l-infinity distance, cos for cosine similarity, dot for dot product
        docs = db.similarity_search(query, filter=filter, distance_metric="cos")

        return docs
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer!

What I was thinking : 
- Providing context from the text file
- Adding system message "Talk like a pirate" when communicating with the OpenAI model.
- I could add "Talk like a pirate" in one of the text files, but I don't think it will take that as an instruction, but knowledge.

Not sure if this is something that can be done or if there are better alternatives.

Comment: you will have to then modify each of the document before storing them in vector db ?

Comment: Is there no way to add a system prompt like we do on chat module on the OpenAI playground? @ZKS

Answer (score 0):

The question pertains to LlamaIndex. Following the [documentation](https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/examples/prompts/prompts_rag.html), a custom prompt can be set as follows:

```py
from llama_index.prompts import LangchainPromptTemplate
from langchain import hub
    
langchain_prompt = hub.pull("rlm/rag-prompt")
    
lc_prompt_tmpl = LangchainPromptTemplate(
    template=langchain_prompt,
    template_var_mappings={"query_str": "question", "context_str": "context"},
)
    
query_engine.update_prompts(
    {"response_synthesizer:text_qa_template": lc_prompt_tmpl}
)
```